# How can I clear console

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

As in the title. How can I clear console in C++?

Comment: On what OS? It's quite a bit different on Linux vs. Windows, just for one example. If you want it for Windows, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866529/how-do-we-clear-the-console-in-assembly/5866648#5866648

Comment: Are you trying to print a bunch of lines and then clear it, or clear it after each line?

Comment: I want to reset console view sometimes. I dont want to spam console with million of newlines.

Comment: I asked [how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777191/how-do-i-clear-a-win32-cmd-console-window-without-using-system-in-c) in C, using a console window handle. [This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777329/2225787) I received. Hopefully, it helps with your case.

Answer (score 83):

**For pure C++**

You can't.  C++ doesn't even have the concept of a console.

The program could be printing to a printer, outputting straight to a file, or being redirected to the input of another program for all it cares.  Even if you could clear the console in C++, it would make those cases significantly messier.

See this entry in the comp.lang.c++ FAQ:

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#clear-screen

**OS-Specific**

If it still makes sense to clear the console in your program, and you are interested in operating system specific solutions, those do exist.

For Windows (as in your tag), check out this link:

- [How do we clear the console in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866529/how-do-we-clear-the-console-in-assembly/5866648#5866648)

Edit: This answer previously mentioned using `system("cls");`, because Microsoft said to do that. However it has been pointed out in the comments that [this is not a safe thing to do](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/). I have removed the link to the Microsoft article because of this problem.

**Libraries (somewhat portable)**

ncurses is a library that supports console manipulation:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ (runs on Posix systems)
- http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm (somewhat old Windows port)

Comment: @Alf: I copy pasted that from the MS article, so downvote them, not me ;)  I'll fix it though.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub edited the answer to remove the MS link suggesting to use `system`, and added a link to your article explaining why.

Comment: For those looking for the removed link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261 although, the code is a simple call to `system(cls);` with the `cstdlib` include. Tread lightly.

Answer (score 67):

For Windows, via Console API:

```
void clear() {
    COORD topLeft  = { 0, 0 };
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;
    DWORD written;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        console, ' ', screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        console, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
        screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
}
```

It happily ignores all possible errors, but hey, it's console clearing. Not like `system("cls")` handles errors any better.

For *nixes, you usually can go with ANSI escape codes, so it'd be:

```
void clear() {
    // CSI[2J clears screen, CSI[H moves the cursor to top-left corner
    std::cout << "\x1B[2J\x1B[H";
}
```

Using `system` for this is just ugly.

Comment: "Using system for this is just ugly." - Why?  Sure looks cleaner to me :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: It spawns a shell process to clear a friggin' console. In what way is that a clean solution? :P It's like using `echo` via `system()` instead of writing to stdout.

Comment: One liner FTW! ;)  Yes, I'm being facetious.  The fact that it spawns a shell process is good info for your answer, tho.  +1 for the *nix version.

Comment: [Using `system()` is a common mistake.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html#CLS)  [So, too, is your suggested method for Unices.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html#ANSI)  [This is what one should do on POSIX systems.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html#POSIX)  You got the Win32 part right, albeit that you didn't incorporate the "scroll back" convention.

Comment: @JdeBP your link is dead. Here's an [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110414123447/http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html)

Answer (score 44):

The easiest way for me without having to reinvent the wheel.

```cpp
void Clear()
{
#if defined _WIN32
    system("cls");
    //clrscr(); // including header file : conio.h
#elif defined (__LINUX__) || defined(__gnu_linux__) || defined(__linux__)
    system("clear");
    //std::cout<< u8"\033[2J\033[1;1H"; //Using ANSI Escape Sequences 
#elif defined (__APPLE__)
    system("clear");
#endif
}
```

- On **Windows** you can use **"conio.h"** header and call **clrscr** function to avoid the use of **system** funtion.

```cpp
#include <conio.h>
clrscr();
```

- On **Linux** you can use ANSI Escape sequences to avoid use of **system** function. Check this reference [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

```cpp
    std::cout<< u8"\033[2J\033[1;1H";
```

- On **MacOS**
  Investigating...

Comment: Doesn't work for me : printing `TERM environment variable not set.`

Answer (score 38):

For Linux/Unix and maybe some others but not for Windows before 10 TH2:

```
printf("\033c");
```

will reset terminal.

Answer (score 10):

outputting multiple lines to window console is useless..it just adds empty lines to it.
sadly, way is windows specific and involves either conio.h (and clrscr() may not exist, that's not a standard header either) or  Win API method

```
#include <windows.h>

void ClearScreen()
  {
  HANDLE                     hStdOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  DWORD                      count;
  DWORD                      cellCount;
  COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

  hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

  /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
  if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return;
  cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
    hStdOut,
    (TCHAR) ' ',
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
    hStdOut,
    csbi.wAttributes,
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

  /* Move the cursor home */
  SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
  }
```

For POSIX system it's way simpler, you may use ncurses or terminal  functions

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

void ClearScreen()
  {
  if (!cur_term)
    {
    int result;
    setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
    if (result <= 0) return;
    }

  putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500     // windows >= 2000 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

void pos(short C, short R)
{
    COORD xy ;
    xy.X = C ;
    xy.Y = R ;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( 
    GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), xy);
}
void cls( )
{
    pos(0,0);
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    cout << string(100, ' ');
    pos(0,0);
} 

int main( void )
{
    // write somthing and wait 
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    cout << string(10, 'a');
    cout << "\n\npress any key to cls... ";
    cin.get();

    // clean the screen
    cls();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To clear the screen you will first need to include the following header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

this will import windows commands. Then you can use the 'system' function to run Batch commands (which edit the console). On Windows in C++, the command to clear the screen would be:

```
system("CLS");
```

And that would clear the console. The entire code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
system("CLS");
}
```

And that's all you need! Goodluck :)

Comment: system("cls") is not a portable solution to this issue, however it does work on Windows systems.

Comment: That is not a "module". C++ does not have "modules". Furthermore, `stdlib.h` is specified by the C standard, and has nothing to do with "importing windows commands" nor indeed Windows itself. Other than that nitpicking, you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() { 
    std::system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

In Linux/Unix:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() { 
    std::system("clear");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is hard for to do on MAC seeing as it doesn't have access to the windows functions that can help clear the screen. My best fix is to loop and add lines until the terminal is clear and then run the program. However this isn't as efficient or memory friendly if you use this primarily and often.

```
void clearScreen(){
    int clear = 5;
    do {
        cout << endl;
        clear -= 1;
    } while (clear !=0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `system("cls")` to clear the screen:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Already mentioned in the accepted answer. No new information here.

Comment: Then get rid of cout/wcout and simply pipe stuff to system("echo " + your output);

Answer (score 2):

In Windows we have multiple options :

1. clrscr() (Header File : conio.h)
2. system("cls") (Header File : stdlib.h)

In Linux, use system("clear") (Header File : stdlib.h)

Comment: Note that any call to system() could be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows:

```
HANDLE h;
CHAR_INFO v3;
COORD v4;
SMALL_RECT v5;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO v6;
if ((h = (HANDLE)GetStdHandle(0xFFFFFFF5), (unsigned int)GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &v6)))
{
    v5.Right = v6.dwSize.X;
    v5.Bottom = v6.dwSize.Y;
    v3.Char.UnicodeChar = 32;
    v4.Y = -v6.dwSize.Y;
    v3.Attributes = v6.wAttributes;
    v4.X = 0;
    *(DWORD *)&v5.Left = 0;
    ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(h, &v5, 0, v4, &v3);
    v6.dwCursorPosition = { 0 };
    HANDLE v1 = GetStdHandle(0xFFFFFFF5);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(v1, v6.dwCursorPosition);
}
```

This is what the system("cls"); does without having to create a process to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Works really well:

```
#include <windows.h>

void clearscreen()
{
    HANDLE hOut;
    COORD Position;

    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    Position.X = 0;
    Position.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, Position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using windows 10 terminal.

```
std::system("cls"); // cls or clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout.flush(); // Flush the output stream
    system("clear"); // Clear the console with the "system" function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't that it is a good practice to use system commands (`system("");`) for
these specific tasks so I made a function for clearing the console screen in
C/C++ and it pretty much does the exact same functionality of the
`system("cls");` but just without calling a system command. (It is for Windows)
you can copy this function to your C/C++ code so you can use this function to
clear the console screen but check that Windows.h library is included in your
code. Here is the code:

```cpp
void clrscr() {
    DWORD Unused = 0;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    COORD zerozeroc = {0, 0};
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    DWORD Length = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ' ', Length, zerozeroc, &Unused);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), csbi.wAttributes, Length, zerozeroc, &Unused);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), zerozeroc);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Please edit to explain how this solves the question in  a different or better way than the 2nd most voted answer, which is pretty much an identical function.

Answer (score -1):

Use System::Console::Clear();

This will clear (empty) the buffer

Comment: **[Error] 'System ' has not been declared.**

Comment: This is for c++/CLI (aka .NET c++)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdlib>

void cls(){
#if defined(_WIN32) //if windows
    system("cls");

#else
    system("clear");    //if other
#endif  //finish
```

}

The just call cls() anywhere

Comment: This isn't what the OP is looking for. Read the comment added to the question.

Answer (score -4):

use: clrscr();

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
      {           
         clrscr();
         cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
         return 0;
      }
```

Comment: "It used to be a function in <conio.h>, in old Borland C compilers. It's not a C++ standard function." http://stackoverflow.com/a/930141/1058115

Answer (score -8):

The easiest way would be to flush the stream multiple times ( ideally larger then any possible console ) 1024*1024 is likely a size no console window could ever be.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  for(int i = 0; i <1024*1024; i++)
      std::cout << ' ' << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The only problem with this is the software cursor; that blinking thing ( or non blinking thing ) depending on platform / console will be at the end of the console, opposed to the top of it. However this should never induce any trouble hopefully.

Comment: This answer is [a common mistake](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/clearing-the-tui-screen.html#ANSI).