# Update output in every second

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std; 

void z()
{
    Sleep(100);
} 

class Car
{
    double fuel;
    double speed;
    double X;
    double Y;
public:
    Car(double n, char *type)
    {
        fuel=n;
        speed=120;
    }
    double Speed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
    void Position(double p, double q)
    {
        X = p;
        Y = q;
    }
    void Move()
    {
        X=X+(Speed()/3600);
        Y=Y+(Speed()/3600);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Car c(70,"Car");
    double x,y;
    c.Position(3.2,2.2);
    cout<<c.Speed()<<endl;
    while(1)
    {
        c.Move();
        c.Position(x,y);
        cout<<x<<","<<y<<endl;
        z();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to show the changes of position in the same line that means in each second the value of position will be updated and show it in the same line replacing the older value but will not create any new line.

Comment: That's not possible with the standard library. You need to use platform-specific functions or a library like `ncurses`.

Comment: Can you provide me any example of it?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6486301/4181011 If you want to keep it "low level" you can just clear the console every second and redraw everything. Or you can go for a library like ncurses.

Comment: thanks @SimonKraemer

Comment: You could revert the cursor to the beginning of the line using `cout<<"\r"<<x<<","<<y;`. Note that I do not write an `endl` at the end.
Apart from that there are some issues with your code: You do neither initialize `x` and `y` in `main()` nor do you update them. Also, there is no way to get the values of `X` and `Y` out of your `Car` class.

Comment: Just in case, `\b` moves cursor one position back, see `echo -e 'a\bz'`.

Comment: Furthering the correct response of @maddin45, I'd add that you probably want to output a bunch of spaces prior to the \r carriage return to overwrite the old output.  Then make sure to flush the output with "std::cout << std::flush".