# Any portable solution and alternative to system() call for clearing console?

Tags: c++, windows, unix, console

I am writing a console application that gives options to user to choose from. After each option is selected I want to clear the console screen. 
Since system(“cls”/“clear") calls are a bad practice and ANSI escape sequence are also non-portable.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour without compromising the portability of the code?

EDIT: I am running  OSX 10.13

Comment: I would use the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses )

Comment: Portable to what? As @JesperJuhl mentioned there is ncurses for UNIX-like systems (UNIX, BSD, Linux, Mac OS X, ...) which is also available for Windows under the name PDCurses.

Comment: @swordfish I want my code portable to windows OS mainly.

Comment: for clear console screen you need call `ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW`. of course not "system"

Comment: @RbMm um ... portable ...

Comment: @Ahmn21 Then please have a look at [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) for your Mac OS X and for Windows you can use the same code but link to [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/)

Comment: @Swordfish - of course for windows only. *I want my code portable to windows OS mainly*. or possible `FillConsoleOutputCharacter  + FillConsoleOutputAttribute` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6487534/6401656)