# C++ clear screen with high efficiency

Tags: c++, cmd

Recently, I have created a c++ program where efficient animation is **required**. Is there a function in c++ that can clear the console with a high efficiency?

P.S. I **DON'T WANT** GUI consoles.
[How can I clear console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486289/how-can-i-clear-console) <- This does not have high efficiency, I tested it.
Environment: windows
Required Efficiency: Invisible for eyes (Like 0.1ms, just no flashing)

Comment: It's often good enough to put the caret at 0,0 position and overwrite the old output.

Comment: why does the answer you link not have sufficient efficiency? What efficiency do you need/want? You need to be more specific otherwise answers will just repeat waht has already been suggested in that post (or this question be closed as duplicate...)

Comment: You also haven't specified the environment.

Comment: Have you read _all 26 answers_ on that duplicate?

Comment: How about PDCurses?