# How do I move a text character across the screen in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where I can use the arrow keys or the WASD keys to move a character across the screen (rpg style). I dont have any clue how to redraw the board in an easy way since there would be so many possible positions. I was thinking about creating a 2d array which would hold the positions. I am not asking for you all to write the code, I am asking simply. Is it possible to make the text character move along positions across the array?

Comment: _'I am not asking for you all to write the code'_ But we're asking you to show some.

Comment: What O/S are you using?  This is highly O/S dependant

Comment: I am using microsoft visual c++ 2010 with windows 7. @bobobobo

Comment: So I'd use `SetConsoleCursorPosition` then. It's fairly easy to use. You can [change the colors too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx). [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to clear the "screen" and redraw the "map" at every change. Another might be to only redraw the lines that have changed. Yet another might be to position the cursor after the character you want to "move", print a backspace followed by e.g. a space, then reposition the cursor to after where you want the new character to be, print another backspace and then the character.

Or simply use a library such as [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: If the OS supports [ConsoleScreenBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx) type functions, you're best off using them. `cls`/full reprint won't perform well on many systems.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) function to move the cursor to any arbitrary XY coordinates that you like.

TO do this, you need a `HANDLE` to the console, which is fairly easy to get

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

[More Windows Console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx).

[See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770853/how-to-use-setconsolecursorposition-func)

Comment: what library do i use to do that. I tried it and it didnt recognize the handle stuff. @bobobobo

Comment: You `#include <windows.h>`