# C++ Go back a line

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a multiple lines system, like this:

```
string readLines(string x)
{
    string temp = "a";
    vector<string> lines(0);
    string result;

    while (1)
    {
        cout << x;
        getline(cin, temp)

        if(temp != "")
        {
            result = result + "\n" + temp;
            lines.push_back(temp);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is working fine, but I want be able to edit the previous line, for example, I'm typing something like this:

```
Helo,
World
```

I want to back on `helo` and fix my typo. How can I do this?

Comment: You want platform specific interactions with the terminal. (AKA, Windows is different from Linux is different from.....).  `ncurses` is a popular library that abstracts the platform specific bits away.

Comment: This is not the nature of the function of the input stream.

Comment: @druckermanly, I work in Windows

Comment: Just the previous line? Or any earlier line? And do you want to preserve "World" while you do your editing of "Helo"?

Comment: @FelipeNascimento First of all you need to remember your previous lines in a different manner, e.g. something like `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a single `std::string` with linebreaks.

Comment: @Beta If I won't preserve "World", it won't be useful.

Comment: @user0042 It's a simple change.

Comment: @FelipeNascimento *It's a simple change* -- What is a "simple change"?  You basically want the console to act like a word processor or text editor?  Neither of those two types of applications are "simple".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie a "simple change" is use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a single `std::string`. I want something like a text editor and I know that it isn't simple.

Answer (score 8):

There is no portable way to go back one line in C++.

You can go to the beginning of the line by printing `\r`, but moving to the previous line requires platform dependent code.

If don't want to use libraries like [Curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), you can try [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Depending on the terminal, `cout << "\033[F"` will move the cursor one line up.

On Windows, there is also the [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15770853/783510) API.