# How to cout on same line as user input? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if it is possible to output something on the same line where the user gave its input

```
int money;
cout << "How much money do you have?" << endl;
cin >> money;
//I want this to appear next to the user input
cout << " $";
```

I hope that you know what i mean and that you can help :)

Edit: I was just wandering if this is possible but as it seems it's not. Not with the standard c++ at least but thanks to everyone who tried to help anyway

Comment: The input is ended with the enter key, how will you expect the i/o to know when an integer is done being typed without an enter?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly...you want the console to show

`How much money do you have?`
`$`

Comment: Do you want the `$` to come before or after the user input?

Comment: It's not possible, input stream wasn't flushed until you press the enter key (meaning, program can't read any input until enter)

Comment: @NathanOliver After

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that when you read the user's input, the terminal interface reads all the way to when the user press the Enter key, and a newline is printed, i.e. the cursor moves to the next terminal line. And then whatever you print appears on that next line.

You can't really avoid this in purely platform-independent C++, since it requires manipulating the file descriptor "under the hood" of the input stream:

- Making it not read all the way to the next newline, or
- Making it not echo all of the characters it reads

(or both). This can be done in a standard way on systems conforming to the [POSIX standard(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) - but it's complicated. You can read a bit more about it in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20482594/1593077); but the bottom line is that you should use a library to do this. One of:

- GNU [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)
- GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

should work for you.

PS: Sometimes your input is not a terminal but a file and you might also need to check whether that is the case.

Comment: For Windows, one can use the IC library, developed in a german C++ forum (https://www.c-plusplus.net/code/ic/), as the conio.h support gradually deteriorated over the years. Despite being in German, the interface should be pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `$` to be printed just beside the input `money` value, one way can be to move one line up and remove the user input line after taking the input and printing money and $ on the very same line.

i.e can be done as:

```
 int money;
 std::cout << "How much money do you have?" << std::endl; 
 std::cin >> money;
 std::cout << "\033[F";
 std::cout << money << " $";`
```

Here's the reference to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134217/c-go-back-a-line) by [Philipp Claßen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783510/philipp-cla%C3%9Fen)

Seems to serve the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am reading this correctly, you just need to put the `$` before your `cin` statement.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int money;
    std::cout << "How much money do you have?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "$";
    std::cin >> money;

    return 0;

}
```

It will then show on the console as
`How much money do you have?`
`$`(insert input here)

Answer (score -1):

You can do damn near anything with judicious use of the comma operator.

```
int money;
std::cout << "How much money do you have?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> money, std::cout << money << " $";
```

Will perform your input and output on one line. You could even do all three on the same line by changing the semicolon on the `std::endl;` out for another comma.

I'm guessing that isn't what you wanted though. You wanted to use the output from std::cin directly without the variable, right? You can take a step further toward that with the comma operator:

```
int money;
std::cout << "How much money do you have?" << std::endl;
std::cout << (std::cin >> money, money) << " $";
```

You could also use a lambda for this purpose, but the syntax overhead of that is greater than what I wrote above

Unfortunately I don't know that you can get rid of two steps of formatted read, then return variable, without using some kind of sequence operator (as I did) or sticking the steps in a function (eg: a lambda), or using some formatted I/O routine that isn't standard C++ (which kind of amounts to the same thing). The problem is that ">>" is **the** C++ standard routine for formatted input, and that operator is designed to return the stream, not the variable read out.

Comment: @StoryTeller - It certainly wouldn't be the first time.