# C escape sequence \033[999D not working properly

Tags: c, escaping

I'm trying to use the escape sequence \033[999D as a brute-force way of moving the cursor to the top row in the console. When I run my program, rather than doing what I intend, it returns a left-pointing arrow and a [999D, on the same line that I was last on.

How should I properly use this escape code? Are there any (better) substitutions?

My (test) code:

```
printf("This is a line\n");
printf("This is another line\n");
printf("\033[999D Overwrite");
```

My output:

```
This is a line
This is another line
←[999D Overwrite
```

Comment: What system are you using?  Ansi escape sequence processing is not enabled by default in the dumb Windows terminal.  The scape sequence to move to home position is different too.

Comment: @chqrlie I'm on Windows 8.1, using a MinGW compiler, if that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the Cursor Position in a Win32 Console Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [**Win32 Console API**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx).

Particularly of interest to you:

- [`GetStdHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231.aspx) (MSDN)
- [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025.aspx) (MSDN)
- [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15770935/119527) showing how to move the cursor to a specific position.
- [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866648/119527) showing how to clear the screen.

Of interest to people looking to set console colors:

- [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047.aspx)

Comment: SetConsoleCursorPosition works PERFECTLY! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems (most likely): The first is that the `D` [VT100 cursor control sequence](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor) is to go back a number of *columns*, which means it will go back a number of columns *on the current row*. It will not change line.

The second and the likely problem the code is printed is because you probably are using the Windows console program (the "DOS prompt") which is very bad at handling VT100 sequences by default.

Comment: I believe I am using the DOS prompt. What should I use, in this case, to go back a specific row and column in the console?

Comment: @tuxedoandex The native Windows console program doesn't really support VT100/ANSI sequences at all, there are ways around it [as detailed in e.g. this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/440558). As for the list of possible cursor control sequences, please follow the link in my answer.

Comment: Is there any way other than ANSI escape sequences to move the cursor? :\