# GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo for length of a single console line

Tags: c, winapi, windows-console

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866529/how-do-we-clear-the-console-in-assembly/5866648#5866648) that is possible to get the length of all output to the console at a given time, however I am wanting to get the length of an individual line in the console (i.e. at a specific `COORD`). Is this possible with Win32 API?

Comment: "I have seen here that is possible to get the length of all output to the console at a given time" um. no. The code in the answer you linked to does not do that.

Comment: @Swordfish Ahh so `dwSize.X` is the max(?) width of the console buffer?

Comment: @Swordfish If that is the case I could use that. My problem is that I am trying to delete lines from the console, however sometimes it overlaps onto the next line and clears that too

Comment: @Yes, `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` gives you the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) to get the width of the console screen buffer. Next do for every position from `width` to `0` in the line you are interested in [`ReadConsoleOutput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutput) and check if the character at the position is a whitespace character (`isspace()`). If it is not you have found the position of the last character in the line and its `X`-coordinate is the lenght of the line.